# How to get the minimum value of unique items based upon a datediff function in t-sql?

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to figure out the minimum time elapsed between two columns, grouped by values in a third column

| ID | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-22 00:00:00 | 2021-08-24 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2021-08-21 00:00:00 | 2021-08-24 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-08-22 00:00:00 | 2021-08-24 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-08-21 00:00:00 | 2021-08-24 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2021-08-22 00:00:00 | 2021-08-24 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2021-08-21 00:00:00 | 2021-08-24 00:00:00 |

From this table, I would like to get the results:

| ID | Elapsed Time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 48 hours |
| 2 | 48 hours |
| 3 | 48 hours |

Currently I have this SQL function

```sql
SELECT ID, datediff(hour, Start Time, End Time) as diff 
FROM t
WHERE 
MIN(diff)
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Jacob, this should give you the results you are looking for:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MIN(DATEDIFF (HOUR, StartTime, EndTime)) AS diff
FROM
    t
GROUP BY
    ID;
```